Do bigger telescopes see more objects primarily because they collect more light, or because they resolve things better?
I encountered this question in an exam recently (which I have simplified to focus on the core question). After describing two modern astronomy telescopes, one big and one small, the question asks why the first telescope is expected to detect more objects than the second one.
My first thought is that for obvious reasons big telescopes collect more light, hence they can detect fainter things, hence they detect more objects.
However, the answer key gives a different solution. It uses the Rayleigh criterion to say that the bigger telescope can resolve more things, hence it should detect more objects.
I'm wondering which effect dominates. Both effects clearly lead in the same direction, but in practice, which effect is the primary reason why bigger telescopes detect more objects?
NB: The question is about radio telescopes detecting pulsars. I imagine some extra considerations here are that 1) pulsars can occur in binaries, making the latter effect more important; and also 2) radio telescopes work by interferometry, so you don't need a single big telescope, you can make do with lots of small telescopes separated by a large distance. However, I suspect both of these effects are well beyond the level of the exam, and it would not be appropriate to expect a student to know them.

If it were the light intensity, which limits the "detection rate" of "small" telescopes there would an obvious way out: We "just" have to increase the time interval of observation. Of course there are other factors which limit the time interval, but in principle we can compensate many of these factors. Thus, if the signal to noise ratio of the light intensity was the limiting factor, we would just increase the time interval -- and yes, we use this often.
However, our current technology is so sensitive that we are able to detect tiny signal. Hence, the mayor problem are disturbances of the air, and the angular resolution. The angular resolution is fundamentally limited by the extend of the detector. This is we placed multiple telescopes around the world, which act like a single giant telescope. A pictorial description is given in this youTube Video.

Are you saying that the latter effect dominates?

Disturbances of the air and the finite angular resolution are two major problems. From my perspective both dominate the signal strength issue.

There are two possible scenarios.

You are observing extended objects: objects large enough that they are resolved even by the smaller telescope. In this case, collecting area is the important factor, as you guessed.

You are observing compact objects that neither telescope can resolve (this is the situation for pulsars). In this case, there is an additional factor, which is the ability to distinguish the source from the background noise. If we imagine two similar telescopes observing the same source, and one has better resolution (e.g., because the atmospheric conditions are better), then the size of the source on the detector will be smaller and thus higher-intensity for the higher-resolution case.[*] If there is a significant background (as there usually is), then the smaller, brighter source will be easier to distinguish from the background noise.


[*] In the similar-telescopes case, the total number of photons received from the source will be the same, but in the higher-resolution observations, those photons will be concentrated into a smaller area on the detector.

Do you know in practice, how many new objects are extended vs. compact?

A telescope with a larger diameter has more resolving power.
For instance: the case of double star systems. Take a double star system that has sufficient magnitude to be photographed with a small aperture telescope (say, 200 milimeter or less).
A comparatively small aperture telescope will not have the resolving power to observe that it's a double star, even while having enough light gathering capacity to observe each constituent star if it would be a single star.
There is a youtube channel by an optical consultant called Jeroen Vleggaar, the name of the channel is Huygens optics
Video Jan 2022:
Telescope Resolution vs. Aperture and Wavelength
In the video:
Generally a propagating wavefront (such as the wavefront of propagating light) will when reflecting remain the same wavefront. However, at any irregularity the energy interacting with that irregularity starts spreading in directions other than parallel to the original direction of propagation. Any such spreading is referred to as diffraction.
The best known form of diffraction is slit diffraction, but any edge gives rise to diffraction effect.
For a telescope: the perimeter of the primary lens/mirror is an edge: a source of diffraction. This diffraction puts an upper limit to the resolving power. The smaller the aperture, the larger the ratio of aperture perimeter to aperture area, hence a larger aperture gives a larger resolving power.
Wikipedia article: angular resolution
The Rayleigh criterion gives the angular resolution in radians as a function of the wavelength $\lambda$ and the diameter $D$ of the circular aperture.
$$ \theta \approx 1.22\frac{\lambda}{D} $$


About radio telescopes:
A radio telescope operating individually is effectively operating in the same way as a telescope working in the optical spectrum.
In the case of radio astronomy the frequency of the measured incoming electromagnetic spectrum is slow enough such that the phase information from multiple far separated telescopes can be communicated over distance, and processed to achieve an image: very-long-baseline interferometery

Optical spectrum
In the optical spectrum coordination like that is much, much harder. There are double mirror telescopes that have optical fiber connection allowing light from both telescopes to interact, allowing image forming.
In order for that to give useful result the length of the connecting conduit must for the duration of the measurment run remain the same to within a fraction of the wavelength of light.
